# PHP Manipulate and sum hexadecimal string

Tags: php, arrays, string, hex

I have in C++ an array of unsigned char, every position of it with an hexadecimal value, like `array[0] = 0xFF; array[1] = 0x2A; array[2] = 0x33;`... and so. Then, there is a function which create a checksum:

```
unsigned char checksum = 0xFF;
for (i = 0; i <= array.size(); i++)
   checksum -= array[i];
```

This works fine, but now I have to migrate the code to PHP.

The first problem I found was that instead of an array, I worked with an string of hexadecimal characters, like `$string = "\xFF\x2A\x33";` because I must write  it through a serial port with dio_write. I tried this code:

```
$checksum = "\xFF";
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($array); $i++)
    $checksum -= $array[$i];
```

But PHP just... don't work this way. It doesn't change the value of `$checksum`. So I tried to transform from string to number

```
$checksum = 255;
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($array); $i++)
        $checksum -= ord($array[$i]);
```

This modify the checksum, but then I must add it to the hexadecimal string and it is... signed. I finally found how to make an unsigned char and the last code I tried has been

```
$checksum = pack("C", "\xFF");
$sum = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($array); $i++)
        $sum += ord($array[$i]);
$checksum = pack("C", ord($checksum) - $sum);
```

But it is just giving me an incorrect checksum. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, finally this worked:

```
$checksum = unpack("C", "\xFF");
$sum = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) 
     $sum += unpack("C",$string[$i])[1];
$checksum = pack("C",$checksum[1]-$sum);
```